# How to get second column value of invoked row in table?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, contextmenu

In below context menu example .. how to get value of second column that invoked it?

[Refer Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/X9tgY/)

tried with `$(this).find('td:second').text()` but it didnt work. :P

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to write such this long code here. Just assign a class name to each `<tr>` like `row` then add click event listener like this:

```
$(".row").click(function () {
  var txt = $(this).children().eq(1).text();
  alert(txt);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/X9tgY/948/)

Comment: This is not what I want, what I'm making is a rightclick-menu. :) But thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your row or invoked row then use cells proberty to access second column

```
$(".row").click(function () {
  var colText = $(this).cells[1].textContent;
  // or-> var colText = row.cells[1].textContent; 
});
```

Comment: Could you please come with a JSfiddle on this comment? I don't understand where to put in this code. :)

Comment: you can add click handler to your rows , my answer above is updated please check it. 
@MatsA hope this answer your question

Comment: I still dont see where to put this @youssef, could you make a fork of the JSFiddle i linked with in the question and write this in? :)